# CheckBoxList C# Values from a SQL Server database separated by ":"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `CheckBoxList` that needs to be populated from a SQL Server database that is separated by `:`.

aspx page

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkTopics" runat="server" CssClass="ChkList">
 <asp:ListItem Value="ABC">ABC</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="D-E-F">D-E-F</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="GHI">GHI</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="J,K,L">J,K,L</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="MNO">MNO</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="PQR">PQR</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

.cs page on what how I am getting the values:

```
SqlConnection conn = null;
conn = new SqlConnection(conn_string);

SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("aspnet_GetAnswers", conn);
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

conn.Open();

SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

if (rdr.Read())
{
  FirstName.Text = rdr.GetValue(2).ToString();
  LastName.Text = rdr.GetValue(3).ToString();
 --> Putting the Code here to read the values and check the values that match.
}

rdr.Close();
conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();
```

From the Database:

> rdr.GetValue(9).ToString();
>
> ABC:GHI:J,K,L:

Comment: So, what problem are you having? Are you saying that you don't know how to "split" a "string"? That's a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like This

```
 string str = GetValue(9).ToString().TrimEnd(':');
 string[] strList = str.Split(':');


 foreach (string s in strList)
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in chkTopics.Items)
            {
                if (item.Value == s)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: But the other ones are not showing up.  The ones in the Database needs to be Selected.

Answer (score 1):

Trim the last colon:

```
string trimmedString = optionsStringFromDb.TrimEnd(':');
```

Get options list:

```
List<string> myOptions = trimmedString.Split(':').ToList();
```

Then populate your CheckBoxList:

```
foreach (string option in myOptions)
{
   chkTopics.Items.Add(new ListItem(option));
}
```

Comment: @mrmcg What do you mean by "doesnt seem to flow" ? You will have to be more specific.

Comment: @mrmcg Is it better now? 'optionsStringFromDb is just a generic name (replace by whatever string you hold your query result)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `string.Split()` on the colon, then create each `LineItem` and add them directly to the `CheckBoxList`:

```
var result = rdr.GetValue(9).ToString();
chkTopics.Items.AddRange(result.Split(':')
                               .Select(x => new ListItem { Text = x, Value = x})
                               .ToArray());
```

If there's a chance you'll have extra colons that would result in empty items, you can remove them using the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` option:

```
.Split(new[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
```

Comment: Checked this one out and it does not select anything.